# Java: alternative to sleep in loop?

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

I need to listen to a serial input continuously, but NetBeans warns "Invoking Thread.sleep in loop can cause performance problems."
I understand why this causes performance problems, but what is the best alternative in Java?

```
public class SerialIO extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    ...
    class RcvTask extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            try {
                SerInputStream sis = new SerInputStream(serialPort);
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(sis);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                while (true) {
                    String line = reader.readLine();
                    parse(line);
                    sleep(RX_SLEEP);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Does your serial com. library have any events or asynchronous functionality?

Comment: The best alternative is to remove the sleep(), you shouldn't need it.  BTW: If you have  a JFrame, will you see the printStackTrace() or will it be discarded?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Why do you need to `sleep` ?

`BufferedReader.readLine()` is a blocking operation.

---

**On the same topic :**

- [Java BufferedReader readline blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776724/java-bufferedreader-readline-blocking)

Comment: Apparently, I've not been getting enough sleep.

Comment: @Jack: I think I have a solution (apologies if you unexpectedly lose the next 8 hours) `JackN.getInstance().sleep(28800000);`