# Java Process stops in the middle of the process

Tags: java, process

I've been trying to google this around for quite a while now, without any success. I'm hoping to get my issue solved here.

**First function:**

```
public void startTFServer(Channel c) {
    try {
        ProcessBuilder procBuilder = new ProcessBuilder("tfs.exe");
        procBuilder.redirectErrorStream();
        Process proc = null;
        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
        proc = procBuilder.start();
        System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
        StreamGobbler gobbler = new StreamGobbler(proc.getInputStream(), "STD_OUT");
        gobbler.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**The thread that captures the process output:**

```
private class StreamGobbler extends Thread {
    InputStream is;
    String type;

    private StreamGobbler(InputStream is, String type) {
        this.is = is;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {               
                System.out.println(type + "> " + line);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**The problem:** 
When running the application the input interrupts at the same place every time. The application I'm running with the "Process class" is a server that required quite some memory to run, can this be one of the reasons for why the process won't finish loading my app? I was thinking that the memory would run out, but I can't really diagnostise it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When you say "interrupts", what do you mean exactly?  Do you get an exception, or does it just hang?

Comment: And where does it do so?  You say it happens in the same place each time - which line appears to be responsible?

Comment: The interruption occurs after it's loading a certain type of Monster (The Server process that's being executed). It's just staying at that line without going any further. No exceptions given (Not even in the ErrorOutputStream). (The application runs just fine when I execute it myself on the desktop, but when wrapped around the Java Process class it seems to run out of memory, at least that's what I think is the case)

Comment: And tfs.exe executes correctly when you don't start it from Java?

Comment: It executes just fine, the issue is that it stops halfway through. I made a video illustrating the cause:
http://www.twitch.tv/feliix_/b/412308381

Comment: The issue has been fixed, sorry for wasting your time, I think I'm just way too tired after having struggling with this application for quite a while now. A.J. solves the issue for me.

Comment: No worries, glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one issues that I notice:

```
procBuilder.redirectErrorStream();
```

This is not what you want. This is a getter method which tells you what the value of the redirectErrorStream property is. It could possibly be that you have errors and you are blocked because they are not read. Therefore, you need to use the setter method: see the API [redirectErrorStream(boolean)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream%28boolean%29)

```
procBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
```

Comment: most welcome :) . but i think the name of the method is misleading and not following the conventions. It would have been much clearer if it was named isRedirectErrorStream() or getRedirectErrorStream().

Comment: I agree! I didn't know it was a "getter", you would think this would do what the name says, well I was wrong :( Amazingly enough there's awesome people out there that can help you with problems such as this within one hour of the post, I'm impressed! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing so sorry if I'm wrong, but I think you are exhausting the output from the external process, not waiting until it finishes in order to keep reading. I mean, basically:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {               
    System.out.println(type + "> " + line);
}
```

If the process stops writing to the output for a second, your logger will stop logging. If it starts writing again, you will be out of the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Sadly it seems it wasn't the cause...
Seems to always stop here:
STD_OUT> [Spawn::addMonster] Can not find Waspoid
STD_OUT> [Spawn::addMonster] Can not find Crawler
STD_OUT> [Spawn::addMonster] Can not find Crawler
STD_OUT> [Spawn::addMonster] Can not find Crawler
STD_OUT> [Spawn::addMonster] Can not find Crawler
STD_OUT> [Spawn::addMonster] Can not find Boozer
There's a lot of more input than that though.

Comment: I think he's right - try sleeping for a second or so within that loop to allow input to accumulate.  May not be a longterm fix, but it should confirm the diagnosis.

Comment: I don't think it is true because readline will block until there is more data. he will recieve null only when the input is terminated. see the following and check the highest ranked answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776724/java-bufferedreader-readline-blocking